# Summary in different languages C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xml-documentation

I need to make summary for two different languages, i know how i can do it for one language

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructor
/// </summary>
/// <param name="FilePath">Full path to file</param>
```

How could i add German variant?

Is, it possible? If yes, show me some example please.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221140/how-to-localize-the-documentation-of-a-net-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the XML documentation "system" is not that flexible.

I don't have a good solution for you, but you can look at using some XML editors to take the original XML produced by Visual Studio and translate it to German - if the XML structure remains the same, you can use the normal tooling (SandCastle or whatever) to produce the German documentation.

Update:

The approach that [@ta.speot.is](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242520/ta-speot-is) [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221140/how-to-localize-the-documentation-of-a-net-library) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530306/summary-in-different-languages-c-sharp/10530358#comment13621098_10530306) is interesting and can be made to work.

In general, you have a complete copy of the documentation comments in a different language, only using an `xml:lang` attribute on the `<summary>` element - the produced document will contain all the XML elements and you can use XSLT to transform and select the language.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, afaik. VS XML documentation mechanism currently supports only one comments block per class member.