# Globalization of <summary> comments

Tags: c#, comments, globalization, summary

I'm asking myself if it is possible to provide the texts written in the  comments in multiple languages.

I mean those:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds two numbers. That's amazing!
/// </summary>
public int Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

I'm writing a little framework and as I can see in the .NET framework the summary info in the intellisense popup appears for me in german. So i think there might be a way to do that for my framework too.

Unfornately I did not find any information about that, so maybe someone of you knows...

I'm also not a big friend of those 'text blocks' above my public functions, it just does not look so good, so I would be happy to here from you if there is maybe a completely other way of doing that.

Comment: Might want to use the term "localization"... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221140/how-to-localize-the-documentation-of-a-net-library as far as the blocks go, some documentation compilers allow you to include a file reference there, but you have to hand-code the xml file instead of it being automatically updated with your code. You may not like the block, but at least its easy to keep consistent.

Comment: Thank you, I did not come up with the word localization :D. I feel so old.