# Show Localized comments in tooltips

Tags: c#, localization, comments, xml-documentation

I want to use English and Persian Comments, both. But in tool-tip I will see just `///Summary` content. So, the question is that:

- Is that possible to see comments in tool-tip in both languages?
- If It's not possible, which documentation is **recommended**? use standard language in summery or localizing that? (for show in tool-tip). Which one is better:

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets All objects of type ....
  /// </summary>
  /// <summary xml:lang="fa">
  /// تمام موجودیت ها از نوع ... را برمیگرداند
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>All Objects of type .... </returns>
  IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
  ```

or:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// تمام موجودیت ها از نوع ... را برمیگرداند
        /// </summary>
        /// <EN>Get The object of type ... </EN>
        ....
```

- If it's better to use localized commenting, can I set it as Right-to-Left?!

Comment: To me, it seems like this will amplify the effect of out-dated source code comments. What happens if someone who only speaks Persian changes the method? They can't really update the English comment, but now it's out of date. Have your team decide on a language for documentation, and stick with it.

Comment: In any case, I would assume the first one is better - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221140/how-to-localize-the-documentation-of-a-net-library - especially if you're generating documentation